# File stream is opened but nothing is printed to console. Program doesn't seem to "finish"

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I'm trying to open a file and print its content line by line to console.

The source code is attached along with a couple screen shots to show my situation. (The redded-out part contain my computer's directories and personal info). As you can see from the screenshot, the program prints "before" but not "after". Of course, neither does it print out anything from coc.txt.

I can't figure out why this is the case. Everything seems correct and I don't see any errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // For exit()

const int MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 300;
int main() {

    FILE  *inputFile;
    inputFile = fopen("coc.txt", "r");
    char lineRead[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    printf("before\n");
    while(!feof(inputFile)) {
        fgets(lineRead, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, inputFile);
        puts(lineRead);
    }
    fclose(inputFile);
    printf("after\n");

}
```

console

[image: screenshot of IDE]

coc.txt

[image: screenshot of text editor]

Comment: Two things: First always check what [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) returns. Secondly, please read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) The first thing would solve the ***crash*** you're having.

Comment: sorry, how do I check what fopen returns?

Comment: As for a hint of your problem, when you run the program, its working directory (which is the root of all relative paths inside your program) is not what you think it is. The file can't be found plain and simple.

Comment: The relevant message is the one you didn't mention: `Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`. That means your program is crashing because of an invalid memory access.

Comment: `inputFile = fopen("coc.txt", "r"); if (!inputFile) { fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s: %s\n", "coc.txt", strerror(errno)); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }` (you also need to include `<string.h>` and `<errno.h>`). What source are you learning C from?

Comment: this was a professor's project but I got the code mostly from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nIilb2kiSU

Comment: Maybe I didn't get what he mentioned correctly.

Comment: @loosethefoolsjuice Yeah, that's awful code in that video.

Comment: @melpomene thanks for your help. now it's giving the error that "Can't open coc.txt: No such file or directory" Is the same folder as the source code the wrong directory to put the text file?

Comment: @loosethefoolsjuice Try putting the text file in the directory your IDE saves the final executable file.

Comment: @Spikatrix it worked holy shit it was like that all along. thank you so much.

Comment: You have just learned an important lesson in C programming.  I.E. always check the returned value from C library functions for error indications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the coc.txt file and the read.c files are in the same folder. I executed your original code and it works fine with VS 2017 on windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggested alternative (not tested yet):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 300
#define NULL 0

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE  *inputFile;
    char fname[MAX_LINE_LENGTH], lineRead[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    /* Get filename from cmd-line */
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf ("USAGE: progname <fname>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Try to open file */
    if ((inputFile = fopen("coc.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("Could not open file");
        return 2;
    }

    /* Now read the file, and echo back a line at a time */
    printf("before...\n");
    while(fgets(lineRead, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, inputFile) != NULL) {
        printf ("%s", lineRead);
    }
    printf("\n...after\n");

    /* Cleanup and exit */
    fclose(inputFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Changes:

1. Be sure to have a "return" from main ().

   In general, a graceful "return" from main() is preferred over a system call to "exit()".
2. Read the input, *then* to check for EOF (fgets() == NULL).
3. Make sure you've opened the file before reading.
4. Rather than hard-coding the filename, we're reading it from the command line.
5. Rather than puts() (which always appends a newline, regardless of whether the string already has a newline), we're using printf().

Comment: `return` is not function; it cannot be "called". An explicit `return` statement is not required in `main` (if you're using C99, which OP is because they're also using a VLA). If we're going for portability, `1` is not necessarily an error status. Your code adds empty lines to the output. There's nothing wrong with calling `exit`.

Comment: @loosethefoolsjuice I'd say it works great now. Instead of crashing, your program now prints an error message and even says why it couldn't open the file: The file you've specified doesn't exist (at least not in the directory it's running in). For quick and dirty way to see where it's running, `#include <stdlib.h>` and add `system("pwd");` to your `main` function.

Comment: To fix the double spacing in the output, use `fputs(lineRead, stdout);` instead of `puts`.

Comment: @melpomene - thank you for the notes.  That's what I get for posting code without actually compiling/tesing it first ;) I made some changes earlier; I trust the OP is squared away with his remaining questions by now.

Comment: Isn't an empty parameter list a deprecated feature?